# Initialise AngularJS service - factory on the document load

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

Sorry for a very stupid question but I just started working with AngularJS and OnsenUI.

I have got a service to get a data from SQLite:

```
module.factory('$update', function () {
    var update = {};
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM event_updates', [], function (tx, results) {
            var rows = results.rows;
            update.items = [];
            if (!rows.length) {} else {
                for (var index = 0; index < rows.length; index++) {
                    update.items.push({
                            "title": rows.item(index).title,
                            "date": rows.item(index).date,
                            "desc": rows.item(index).desc
                    });
                }
            }
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
    return update;
});
```

And a controller which is using the data:

```
module.controller('UpdatesController', function ($scope, $update) {
    $scope.items = $update.items;
});
```

As soon as my page is loaded the content is not displayed and I need to click twice to call a page with the code below to see the content:

```
<ons-list ng-controller="UpdatesController">
                        <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" class="list-item-container" ng-repeat="item in items" ng-click="showUpdate($index)">
                            <div class="list-item-left">

                            </div>
                            <div class="list-item-right">
                                <div class="list-item-content">
                                    <div class="name">{{item.title}}</div> <span class="desc">{{item.desc}}</span>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

Can anybody help how can I initialise the controller as soon as page is loaded with all content. Sorry if it is a stupid question but I am really struggling. Appreciate your help a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the result of the request in the factory and retrieve those instead.

```
module.factory('$update', function () {
   var update = {};
   var requestValues = function(){ // store the results of the request in 'update'
     // Your db.transaction function here
   }

   var getUpdates = function(){ // retrieve the values from 'update'
     return update;
   }

   return{
     requestValues : requestValues,
     getUpdates : getUpdates 
   }
});
```

And then in you controller:

```
module.controller('UpdatesController', function ($scope, $update) {
  $update.requestValues();
  $scope.items = $update.getUpdates();
});
```

You could then get the values from anywhere in you solution (by using `$update.getUpdates`) without having to make an extra http request.

Comment: thank you. I have got an error : **Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression** on this line: $update.requestValues; And unfortunately it doesn't load the content as soon as page is loaded, have to click twice to see the content.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to call them as functions `()`. Se updated answer